# In Google Analytics, show eCommerce order numbers based on first click attribution

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, tracking, click-tracking

Google Analytics usually reports everything based on last click attribution. However, GA recently added some reports to compare metrics based on different attribution models like first click.

Is it possible to show eCommerce reports (specifically order numbers) based on first click attribution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is - you can balance the worth of a user's first touch to 100% (which ignores subsequent hits from that user when attributing value) under your view options in attribution models. This then effects everything under that view. If you only occasionally want to see this then create a new view and label it something appropriate.

Compare the goal value of your referrals and you'll see them all weighted toward the first touch only now. This means if a referral was anywhere else in the flow it will not gain value from that user.